# Retweet and destroy tweet using twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing an application which can send tweets to my twitter profile.
Now I need to implement retweet and delete tweet function. I implement those like following but no success. can any one help me!!

/* Delete tweet function */

```
$twitteroauthPost = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$token = $twitteroauthPost->getRequestToken();    

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,$token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
$result = $connection->post('statuses/destroy', array('id' => $postId));
```

/* Retweet function */

```
$twitteroauthPost = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$token = $twitteroauthPost->getRequestToken();    

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,$token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
$result = $connection->post('statuses/retweet', array('id' => $postId));
```

Then it return this

```
(
    [request] => /1/statuses/retweet.json
    [error] => Could not authenticate you.
)
```

Comment: have you set up the permissions correctly on the dev site, ie where your got the authentication credentials

Comment: I got credentials from dev.twitter.com. Access level is : Read and write

Answer (score 2):

This error means that the authorization header that gets sent to twitter is not correct.  Since you are using a library that's been tested and is widely used I'm guessing that you have got your CONSUMER_KEY or CONSUMER_SECRET wrong.  I'd just double check these.